# What's the term for this Design Element?

Tags: designers, terminology

I am looking for a term of this flowerish design element so I can look up some more variations.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is called a Laurel Wreath: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurel_wreath

Comment: And this is where the term "laurels" (as in "we cannot rest on our laurels") comes from

Comment: Just another piece of useless information I thought I would share: laurel (Laurus nobilis) is what gives us bay leaves, the kind you put in a stew. Roman emperors wore a laurel wreath on their head, like a crown.